# Why does Boost MPL have integral constants?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, metaprogramming, boost-mpl

Since you can take integral values as template parameters and perform arithmetic on them, what's the motivation behind `boost::mpl::int_<>` and other integral constants? Does this motivation still apply in C++11?

Comment: If this is really of interest to you, read the book "C++ Template Metaprogramming", by the main authors of Boost MPL, it explains the motivations behind all these kinds of things. And, this is not only valid for C++11, it has been made standard in C++11 with [std::integral_constant](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can take integral values as template parameters, but you cannot take both *types* and *non-type template parameters* with a single template. Long story short, treating *non-type template parameters* as *types* allows for them to be used with a myriad of things within *MPL*.

For instance, consider a metafunction `find` that works with types and looks for an equal type within a sequence. If you wished to use it with *non-type template parameters* you would need to reimplement new algorithms 'overloads', a `find_c` for which you have to manually specify the *type* of the integral value. Now imagine you want it to work with mixed integral *types* as the rest of the language does, or that you want to mix *types* and *non-types*, you get an explosion of 'overloads' that also happen to be harder to use as you have to specify the type of each non-type parameter everywhere.

This motivation does still apply in *C++11*.

This motivation will still apply to *C++y* and any other version, unless we have some new rule that allows conversion from *non-type template parameters* to *type* template parameters. For instance, whenever you use `5` and the template requests a type instantiate it with `std::integral_constant< int, 5 >` instead.

Comment: C++y?  I thought it was C++1y?

Comment: Would you show some code demonstrating the problem, and then show the working version?

Answer (score 14):

tldr; Encoding a value as a type allows it to be used in far more places than a simple value. You can overload on types, you can't overload on values.

K-Ballo's answer is great.

There's something else I think is relevant though. The integral constant types aren't only useful as template parameters, they can be useful as function arguments and function return types (using the C++11 types in my examples, but the same argument applies to the Boost ones that predate them):

```
template<typename R, typename... Args>
  std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof...(Args)> 
  arity(R (*)(Args...))
  { return {}; }
```

This function takes a function pointer and returns a type telling you the number of arguments the function takes.  Before we had `constexpr` functions there was no way to call a function in a constant expression, so to ask questions like "how many arguments does this function type take?" you'd need to return a *type*, and extract the integer value from it.

Even with `constexpr` in the language (which means the function above could just `return sizeof...(Args);` and that integer value would be usable at compile time) there are still good uses for integral constant types, e.g. tag dispatching:

```
template<typename T>
  void frobnicate(T&& t)
  {
    frob_impl(std::forward<T>(t), std::is_copy_constructible<T>{});
  }
```

This `frob_impl` function can be overloaded based on the `integer_constant<bool, b>` type passed as its second argument:

```
template<typename T>
  void frob_impl(T&& t, std::true_type)
  {
    // do something
  }

template<typename T>
  void frob_impl(T&& t, std::false_type)
  {
    // do something else
  }
```

You could try doing something similar by making the boolean a template parameter:

```
frob_impl<std::is_copy_constructible<T>::value>(std::forward<T>(t));
```

but it's not possible to partially specialize a function template, so you couldn't make `frob_impl<true, T>` and `frob_impl<false, T>` do different things.  Overloading on the *type* of the boolean constant allows you to easily do different things based on the *value* of the "is copy constructible" trait, and *that* is still very useful in C++11.

Another place where the constants are useful is for implementing traits using SFINAE. In C++03 the conventional approach was to have overloaded functions that return two types with different sizes (e.g an `int` and a struct containing two `int`s) and test the "value" with `sizeof`. In C++11 the functions can return `true_type` and `false_type` which is far more expressive, e.g. a trait that tests "does this type have a member called `foo`?" can make the function indicating a positive result return `true_type` and make the function indicating a negative result return `false_type`, what could be more clear than that?

As a standard library implementor I make **very** frequent use of `true_type` and `false_type`, because a lot of compile-time "questions" have true/false answers, but when I want to test something that can have more than two different results I will use other specializations of `integral_constant`.