# What is std::false_type or std::true_type?

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I saw its usage as below

```
template <typename T>
struct DependentFalse : std::false_type
{};
```

Then, it is used here

```
template <typename T>
class RadarSensor
{
    static_assert(DependentFalse<T>::value, "RadarSensor must be created using Identifier template");
};
```

I do not have idea what is it used for?

What is DependentFalse structure?

Comment: Look up: type traits

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51523965/template-dependent-false

Comment: Better dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20368187/27678

Comment: Is there more code? I would like to know if there is a template specialisation for DependentFalse or RadarSensor?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`std::false_type` is used as a building block in type traits and is defined as `std::integral_constant<bool, false>` (which I will skip over here). It's definition boils down to something like this (simplified):

```
struct false_type {
    static constexpr bool value = false;
    constexpr operator bool() const noexcept { return value; }
    // There is more here, but it doesn't really matter for your question
};
```

Similarly:

```
struct true_type {
    static constexpr bool value = true;
    constexpr operator bool() const noexcept { return value; }
    // There is more here, but it doesn't really matter for your question
};
```

It is used to represent the *values* `false` and `true` as *types*. This is useful in type traits where you let a class template inherit from either `std::false_type` or `std::true_type` for different (partial) specializations, depending on some condition met by the template argument. Doing so allows one to test whether a given type satisfies the condition of the type trait and to obtain a compile time constant *value* indicating the result through access to the static `value` member which is inherited from either `std::false_type` or `std::true_type` or alternative through conversion of an instance of the type trait using the conversion operator.

What you are showing here is a simple type trait which always (for all `T`) evaluates to `std::false_type`. It is used in `static_asserts` that should always fail when the template they are located in is instantiated. This is necessary, because a `static_assert` that does not dependent on a template parameter is triggered already at the point of definition, rather than the point of instantiation, therefore making every program containing something like `static_assert(false);` ill-formed.

Comment: The fact it has a `constexpr` convert-to-bool that is highly useful in versions of C++ after C++11 is probably something everyone working with `std::true_type` should know about.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I have added it.

Answer (score 0):

There is likely a specialisation of `DependentFalse` for `Identifier` that might look like this:

```
 template<class ... Args>
 class  DependentFalse<Identifier<Args...>> : public std::true_type {}
```

This makes sure that you can not compile a `RadarSensor`, as long as the template parameter does not fullfill whatever is needed for the specialisation (in this case being of type Identifier).

Comment: I don't think so, that would be counter to the naming. Rather there is probably a specialization of `RadarSensor` which does not contain the `static_assert`.