# Structs, templates use, and inheritance questions

Tags: c++

I recently came across a script(below) in which I do not understand why we need to have structs in this script and why they have to inherit false/true types. I also do not understand why "template" is repeated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct is_vector: false_type {}; //<- why does the struct have to inherit something and what does it do?
template<typename T, typename Alloc>
struct is_vector<vector<T, Alloc>> : true_type {};

template<class T>
void func(const vector<T> & vec){    
    for(const auto & x : vec)   
        if constexpr (is_vector<T>::value) 
            func(x);        
    else
            cout << x << ' ';
}
int main(){
  func(vector<int>{5,10,15});
  func(vector<vector<int>>{{5,10,15},{20,25,30}});
}
```

Comment: Read about *template specializaton* and the [meaning of `true/false_type`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58694521/what-is-stdfalse-type-or-stdtrue-type).

Comment: It doesn't _have_ to inherit from `false_type` or `true_type` but it saves some typing.

Comment: Inheriting from `false_type` gives the class a `value` member with the value `false`; and similarly `true_type` provides the member with the value `true`. That member is then checked by `if constexpr`. You could define the member yourself, it's just that deriving from those classes is a quick shorthand.

Comment: Unrelated: You should add a deduction guide to make it simpler to use. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/5VDFrS)